# Add a column with filename to Psql table in nifi

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I have a table that consists of 2 columns

```
 cattlegendernm | price 
----------------+-------    
 Female         | 10094     
 Female         | 12001     
 Male           | 12704
```

I would like to add another column with filename to this table using a nifi processor.
Which Processor and SQL query should I use for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a ***PutSQL*** processor would be suitable to add such a DDL statement like

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD COLUMN filename VARCHAR(150)
```

into the ***SQL Statement*** attribute of the ***properties*** tab as illustrated below

[image]

where ***PostGRES_DB*** represents a pre-configured ***Controller Service*** to interact with the database